# Using an existing Android emulator in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator

So this is probably really simple and easy but I've been unable to find anything on the googles.

Once I've got an android emulator up and running from within IntelliJ Idea, and tested my project in it and then write a little more code, how do I push the new build onto the existing emulator?

I'm asking this because right now, I have to close the emulator each time and then relaunch the emulator again which takes forever to boot up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing take a look at the GenyMotion emulator it is way faster. There is a free version with a few of the bells and whistles disabled but it is way better than the AVD's provided with AS or Eclipse.  Make sure you set a configuration for the app.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!